# Is this question about Adeos on-topic for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, scope

Are these kinds of questions considered off-topic? What else can be the reason that I have received 3 downvotes?

**[Adeos's role w.r.t Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9965722/adeoss-role-w-r-t-linux)**

> > The event pipeline
> >     The fundamental Adeos structure one must keep in mind is the chain of client domains
> >     asking for event control. A domain is a kernelbased
> >     software component which can ask
> >     the Adeos layer to be notified of:
> >     · Every incoming external interrupt, or autogenerated
> >     virtual interrupt;
> >     · Every system call issued by Linux applications,
> >     · Other system events triggered by the kernel code (e.g. Linux task switching,
> >     signal notification, Linux task exits etc.).
>
> From: Life with Adeos
>
> Question: Adeos is supposed to be between the hardware and the Linux kernel, I can understand about Adeos telling the Linux about hardware interrupts but **Why should Adeos know about the "system call" issued by Linux**?

Comment: It seems by the close votes that the community believes your question belongs on [su].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This probably *could* be considered on-topic, but not in the way you asked it. If your question is simply, "Why would the Adeos nanokernel need to intercept system calls?", then lead with that - make that your title, explain your confusion, and *then* link to some background information on Adeos.

The way it reads here, I have a bit of trouble determining if your question is concerned with understanding how system calls / software interrupts matter when the purpose of Adeos is to share *hardware* resources... Or if you're just struggling to interpret the text on the Adeos web page.

It's important that when you ask a question you strive to make it clear up-front what that question *is*. Don't expect folks to do a whole lot of research before deciding whether or not your question is on-topic - and if you *do* make them do so, expect down-votes for being unclear. As a rule of thumb, your title should *summarize your question*.

Comment: I'd suggest you edit your question on SU for clarity then. Don't re-post.